# Reading from a file from bufio with a semi complex sequencing through file

Tags: go

So there may be questions like this but its not a super easy thing to google. Basically I have a file thats a set of protobufs encoded and sequenced as they normally are from the protobuf spec.

So think of the bytes values being chunked something like this throughout the file:

[EncodeVarInt(size of protobuf struct)] [protobuf stuct bytes]

**So you have a few bytes read one at a time that are used for large jump of a read on our protof structure.**

My implementation using the os ReadAt method on a file currently looks something like this.

```
// getting the next value in a file context feature 
func (geobuf *Geobuf_Reader) Next() bool {
    if geobuf.EndPos <= geobuf.Pos {
        return false
    } else {
        startpos := int64(geobuf.Pos)

        for int(geobuf.Get_Byte(geobuf.Pos)) > 127 {
            geobuf.Pos += 1
        }
        geobuf.Pos += 1

        sizebytes := make([]byte,geobuf.Pos-int(startpos))

        geobuf.File.ReadAt(sizebytes,startpos)

        size,_ := DecodeVarint(sizebytes)

        geobuf.Feat_Pos = [2]int{int(size),geobuf.Pos}
        geobuf.Pos = geobuf.Pos+int(size)

        return true
    }
    return false
}

//  reads a geobuf feature as geojson
func (geobuf *Geobuf_Reader) Feature() *geojson.Feature {
    // getting raw bytes
    a := make([]byte,geobuf.Feat_Pos[0])
    geobuf.File.ReadAt(a,int64(geobuf.Feat_Pos[1]))

    return Read_Feature(a)
}
```

How can I implement something like bufio or other chunked reading mechanisms to speed up so many file ReadAt's? Most bufio implementations I've seen are for having a specific delimitter. Thanks in advance hopefully this wasn't a horrible question.